# Export Posts with specific custom fields by sql

Tags: posts, plugin-development, sql

My development site has posts with custom fields. Meanwhile my live site has more posts added while I'm working on my development site. Now I want to export posts with specific custom fields from live site and import those posts to my development site.

I do not want to do this using WP export/import tool. I want to do this by sql.

That means I will export tables from live site and import those to my development site. Keep in mind that I want specific custom fields.

My questions are :

What should be the best approach do achieve this goal???

Which tables do I need to export from the live site???

What should I do about post authors and post terms???

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi The tables that you need to consider is

wp_posts - Which contains all the details about the posts.
wp_postmeta - Which is used to store the meta details for a post with relation to post_id.

Query will be

```
Select * FROM wp_posts a, wp_postmeta b WHERE a.post_status = 'published' AND a.post_id = b.post_id AND b.meta_key = 'Your Custom Field';
```

wp_terms, wp_term_relationships contains the terms and tags which is related to a particular post.

wp_terms - tag details.
wp_term_relationships - how each term is related to a particular post. (object_id = post_id)

Cheers Happy Coding.